# MobX - Map with extendObservable not rerending with new value?

Tags: javascript, mobx

So in `mobx` when you add new fields to an observable, via `extendObservable` it does not rerender the component, and the idea is to use an observable map instead, which should pick up the new changes (keys/values) and rerender the component.

On load of the component, I see the `Name` and the `Language` values assigned in the constructor. So that's working as expected. Perfect!

The issue is after assigning the new field `Year` below via the button using the `addYear` action, I am able to alert out the value for it, which means it is in the map, which should rerender the component, but it does not. Here is the code:

```
@observer
export default class Book extends Component {
    @observable book = asMap({});

    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      const map = this.book;
      map.set('book', {name: 'The Secret', language: 'English'});
    }

    @action addYear() {
      const year = {year: '2006'};

      const map = this.book;
      if (map.has('book')) {
        extendObservable(map.get('book'), toJS(year));
        alert(map.get('book').year); // Shows Year but does not rerender
      }
    }

    render() {
      const map = this.book;
      const book = map.has('book') && map.get('book');

      return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                              onPress={() => this.addYear()}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Add Year!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <Text>Name: {book.name}</Text>
            <Text>Language: {book.language}</Text>
            <Text>Year: {book.year}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
}
```

Any idea why it's not rerendering the component on addition of `Year` to the book map?

Comment: Why do you mix a state object with an observer react class? Like this you have a antipattern that should be fixed either with external state object or with the state of the react component.

Comment: @RickyA not sure what you mean. I am trying to use mobX, not react's state, and I am trying to put to the test an observable that gets new keys/values to refresh automatically when a new key/value are added to it.

Comment: yes, but normally you create one object as a store (BookStore :) that holds the mobx observables. Then the react component is the observer of that store and calls its actions to change data in the store. I am not sure mobx can handle the observers and the observables in one class correctly.

Comment: the whole point of this store thingie is that you can connect multiple react components to the same store and share its data. The way you build it like above is pointless since you could more easily and should use the components state (this.setState) to update its state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just have a map representing a book, you could just set the year property [**like this**](http://jsbin.com/nafosipawe/edit?js,output):

```
@observer
class App extends React.Component {
  @observable book = asMap({
    name: 'The Secret', 
    language: 'English'
  });
  addYear = () => {
    this.book.set('year', '2006');
  };
  render() {
     const year = this.book.get('year');
     return <div> 
       <div>Name: {this.book.get('name')}</div>
       <div>Language: {this.book.get('language')}</div>
       {year ? <div>Published Year: {year}</div> : null}
       <button onClick={this.addYear}> Add Year </button>
     </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Tholle, this is really close but outputs all the values in a row. I am trying to get the output of the values in different areas of the template, for example, Name: `this.book.name` and there can be other content after it, then Published Year: `this.book.year` I tried that out but it's not working. Any idea how to explicitly call the individual values of the observable book and still have it rerender?